# Stop the 'You can temporarily connect' popup when I am near someone that happens to also have airpods

Tags: ipad, airpods

I have my iPad, iPhone, and Airpods.  Sometimes I am in places where there are other people that happen to also have airpods. Whenever I am in range I get an annoying popup on my devices offering to share with these random devices that happen to be near me.

I want to disable this prompt! I don't want to share audio with any devices other then the airpods I own and have associated with my devices.

I have seen similar threads/posts on other locations, but nobody seems to have an answer.

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250693611
- https://www.reddit.com/r/airpods/comments/e8aq5l/anyone_know_how_to_disable_audio_sharing_this/